# how to store a quiz score in a txt file using c++

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming and one of the projects I would like to tackle would be a quiz, the problem is I do not know how to store my quiz scores in a text file, can someone help plz? A given example would be nice

Comment: There is a list of good books [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2):

Here is slightly modified example of the one given in [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)

```
// basic file operations
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main () {
  std::ofstream myfile("example.txt");
  if(myfile.is_open())
  {
     myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
     myfile << 1 << 2 << 3;
  }
  else 
  {
     std::cout << "error opening file" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This creates `example.txt` in your working directory if it does not exist yet, opens it, streams to it and closes the file as `myfile` is destroyed. Now the file contains the following text:

```
Writing this to a file.
123
```

Comment: You should also check  if (myfile.is_open()) and then pass data there I guess

Comment: I updated my answer. Sorry for mixing cplusplus and cppreference. I am simply not focused enough today...

Comment: thanks for that, really helped out. Have a nice day ahead!